# Using global variables across YAML files within Artillery

Tags: javascript, global-variables, app.yaml, artillery

Is there any way in which I can say, define a URI that will be used in different .yml files for different Artillery load tests?

I am wanting to use the same URI within a number of .yml files to define the `target` within the `config` section.

I saw the following on the [Artillery docs](https://artillery.io/docs/script-reference/):

> Values can be set dynamically via environment variables which are available under $processEnvironment template variable.
>
> For example, to set a default HTTP header for all requests via the SERVICE_API_KEY environment variable

They show an example doc of:

> export SERVICE_API_KEY="012345-my-api-key"
>
> artillery run my-test.yml

However I am unsure of how to implement this, as I am using the package.json file to run the `artillery run my-test.yml` command.

Comment: [YML](https://fdik.org/yml/) is not the same as [YAML](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html) and the recommended extension for YAML files has been `.yaml` at least since Sep 2006. The example you quote used the proper filename, which you seem to have misread/misrepresented in the rest of your post..

Comment: @Anthon - Whoops. Mixing web examples and my own codebase there. Edited to be consistent now. Any thoughts on the matter, other than syntactic mistakes on my part?

Comment: Sorry, but no. I get notified on posts tagged with [tag:yaml] (as I developed a Python load/dumper package for YAML), but I don't know Artillery.

Comment: @Anthon apologies, clicked the first one I saw. Have changed the tag to app.yaml now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured this out on my own:

In package.json make a new script.  Call it whatever you like, and do something similar to this:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "set ENV=https://yoursite.com&&artillery run -k yourtest.yml"
}
```

in the .yml file itself something like this:

```
config:
  target: "{{$processEnvironment.ENV}}"
```

call it like this:

```
npm run start
```

Comment: Is there a way in which you would be able to specify multiple variables?

Comment: You could split up a common-config.yml as another option.  See --config section here: https://artillery.io/docs/cli-reference/

Answer (score 0):

IDK why but for me export worked, I mean:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "export ENV=https://yoursite.com&&artillery run -k yourtest.yml"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something perhaps not very sophisticated but that works is this:

```
config:
  target: "https:/"
```

Then in the url you can put the rest of the URL for each cases

```
- get:
    url: "/myUrl1.com"

- get:
    url: "/myUrl2.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you can use [`"{{ $env.VAR_NAME }}"`](https://www.artillery.io/docs/reference/test-script#using-environment-varables).